# Read file, parse by tabs and insert into mysql database with Bash Script

Tags: mysql, regex, bash, file

I am doing a bash script to read a file line by line, parse and insert it in mysql database.

The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start!"

while IFS='     ' read -ra ADDR;
do
   for line in $(cat filename)
   do
      regex='(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\s(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)'
      if [[$line=~$regex]]
      then
         $line='20$3-$2-$1 $4';
      fi
      echo "insert into table (time, total, caracas, anzoategui) values('$line', '$line', '$line', $
   done | mysql -uuser -ppassword database;
done < filename
```

The file 'filename' with data is something like this:

```
15/08/13 09:34:38       17528                                   5240    399     89      460     159     1107    33240
15/08/13 09:42:57       17528                                   5240    399     89      460     159     1107    33240
15/08/13 10:20:03       17492                                   5217    394     89      459     159     1101    33245
15/08/13 11:20:02       17521                                   5210    402     90      462     158     1112    33249
15/08/13 12:20:04       17540                                   5209    396     90      459     160     1105    33258
```

And its dropping this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`LOAD DATA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement. Do any transformations you have to on your file first, then

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename' INTO table (time, total, caracas, anzoategui)
```

Tab separated fields is the default.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating your `sql` file using `awk` and then sourcing it from `mysql`. Re-direct the output once it looks ok to you into a new file (say `insert.sql`) and source it from `mysql` command line. Something like this:

```
$ cat file
15/08/13 09:34:38       17528                                   5240    399     89      460     159     1107    33240
15/08/13 09:42:57       17528                                   5240    399     89      460     159     1107    33240
15/08/13 10:20:03       17492                                   5217    394     89      459     159     1101    33245
15/08/13 11:20:02       17521                                   5210    402     90      462     158     1112    33249
15/08/13 12:20:04       17540                                   5209    396     90      459     160     1105    33258
```

```
$ awk -F'[/ ]+' -v q="'" '{print "insert into table (time, total, caracas, anzoategui) values ("q"20"$3"-"$2"-"$1" "$4q","q$5q","q$6q","q$7q");"}' file
insert into table (time, total, caracas, anzoategui) values ('2013-08-15 09:34:38','17528','5240','399');
insert into table (time, total, caracas, anzoategui) values ('2013-08-15 09:42:57','17528','5240','399');
insert into table (time, total, caracas, anzoategui) values ('2013-08-15 10:20:03','17492','5217','394');
insert into table (time, total, caracas, anzoategui) values ('2013-08-15 11:20:02','17521','5210','402');
insert into table (time, total, caracas, anzoategui) values ('2013-08-15 12:20:04','17540','5209','396');
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash uses POSIX character classes.  So instead of `\d` you could use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` to match a digit.

Also, there must be spaces in between the brackets and operator in your regex test.  So `[[$line=~$regex]]` would be fixed by doing `[[ $line =~ $regex ]]`.

In order to access the regular expressions enclosed in parentheses, you must access the builtin array variable `BASH_REMATCH`.  So, to access the first match, you'd reference `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`, the second `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`, and so on.